# iOS: Unable to parse push notification from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to iOS and currently working on an dating app. I have already implemented `firebase push` in android and it works fine, but when notification is coming on iOS device, it is coming in raw `json` format.

On searching I came to know that iOS is providing fixed format for push notification like:

```
{ 
  "aps": {
         "alert":"Testing.. (0)",
         "badge":1,
         "sound":"default",
         "mutable-content": 1,
         "attachment-url": ""
         }
}
```

but my `json` data is coming in other format and I am unable to parse it to show proper notifications.

`My Format`

```
{
 "aps" : {
         "badge" : 50,
         "alert" : {
                    "body" : "{\"notificationId\":\"Flootapp\",\"DateMatchHistoryId\":\"BJgV-_PYX\",\"id\":\"Syn-XlnHX\",\"message\":\"Congratulations! You have a match with Rishi Raj. Confirm quickly\",\"type\":\"matched\"}",
                    "title" : "Floot"
                   }
          },
 "gcm.message_id" : "0:1537863976816788%835a2461835a2461",
 "message" : "{\"notificationId\":\"Flootapp\",\"DateMatchHistoryId\":\"BJgV-_PYX\",\"id\":\"Syn-XlnHX\",\"message\":\"Congratulations! You have a match with Rishi Raj. Confirm quickly\",\"type\":\"matched\"}",
 "badge" : "50",
 "messageFrom" : "Floot",
 "alert" : "{\"notificationId\":\"Flootapp\",\"DateMatchHistoryId\":\"BJgV-_PYX\",\"id\":\"Syn-XlnHX\",\"message\":\"Congratulations! You have a match with Rishi Raj. Confirm quickly\",\"type\":\"matched\"}",
 "google.c.a.e" : "1"

 }
```

Anything I am missing here. Please help.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you provide us with your JSON data format?

Comment: "my json data is coming in other format" What other format?

Comment: @StacySmith updated my format.

Comment: @Larme updated my format. Please have a look.

Comment: You have JSON within JSON. You need to call `JSONSerialization` on it.

Comment: @Larme can you give me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `JSON as Data <= JSONSerialization() => Swift Array/Dictionary`. `Data <= String(data:,encoding:)/data(encoding:) => String`. You just have to call the correct methods to transform from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will helps you.
First you need to find user info from your push notification response.

You need to set key which you want to access in this "YourKey". and you will get `[String: Any]` types of object. after that you can access your value inside from `dict` object.

if you fetch `message` data then you need to set `message` in place of `YourKey`.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
            let info = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            if let notiStr = info["YourKey"] as? String, let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: notiStr) {
                  print(items: dict)
            }
            return completionHandler()
}


func convertToJson(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: This method is not getting called, instead public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {} it is getting called.

Answer (score 4):

May this will help you. use this in appdelegate:

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
            print(userInfo)
            let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary
            print(aps!)
            let alert = aps!["alert"] as? NSDictionary
            print(alert!)
            let body = let body = alert![AnyHashable("body")] as? String
            let title = alert!["title"] as? String
            print(title!)
            print(body!)

           let jsonData = body?.data(using: .utf8)!

           let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
           print(json)
           let notificationId = json["notificationId"] as! String
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "YourAppName"
        content.body = userInfo.description
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "YourAppName", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let currentBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
        let updatedBadgeNumber = currentBadgeNumber + 1
        if (updatedBadgeNumber > -1) { UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = updatedBadgeNumber }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){ (error) in
        }
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "YourAppName"

        guard
            let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let _ = alert["body"] as? String,
            let _ = alert["title"] as? String
            else {
                return
        }
        content.title = (alert["title"] as? String)!
        content.body = (alert["body"] as? String)!

        notificationText = ""

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "YourAppName", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){ (error) in
        }
        self.backGround = "true"

    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `NSDictionary` (or NSStuff) in Swift when there is an equivalent. Also, that's a lot of force unwrap. Some don't make sense: `let alert = aps!["alert"] as? NSDictionary` followed by `print(alert!)`.

Comment: @MaheshShahane push is stopped getting received after I do this.

Comment: I don't want to print, I want to show notifications.